# Setting proxy as System properties not working

Tags: java, proxy, pac

I'm trying to set a proxy to use in my application. When I try to set it as a system property:

```
Proxy proxy = ... // code to retrieve proxy from .pac file
InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));
```

it throws `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` when I try to connect to a URL:

```
URL url = new URL(urlToConnect);
HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Exception thrown in this line
```

But, if I set the proxy as a parameter to `openConnection()`:

```
HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

my code works and I am able to connect to URL, but this solution is impracticable since I have many `openConnection()` in my code.

How can I make it work when using it as system properties?

Comment: did you try to establish the connection from browser with same url that is throwing exception ?

Comment: yes.. it works ok @MSach

Comment: is the url http or https ?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html): _On recent Windows systems and on Gnome 2.x systems it is possible to tell the java.net stack, setting this property to true, to use the system proxy settings (both these systems let you set proxies globally through their user interface). Note that this property is checked only once at startup._

Are you on Windows or Gnome 2.x? If not, sounds like you can't use the property. If you are, then set the property on the command line, not within your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL I was trying to access was https and I was setting `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`. Changing it to `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyHost`, it worked